# Angular value on onclick

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I would like to know how I could do this correctly

```
<button id="btn" onclick="{{team.p_slot_01}}")>App</button>
```

I have tried several things but nothing worked

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: The most correct way would be to learn the basics from the documentation https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: And make a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing a string through a click, I will recommend making a function and then triggering it here `click="functionName("")"` and then creating that function in the component. If you can further explain the scenario, I can give more suggestions

Comment: Sure about `onClick`?

Comment: sorry I mean click="functionName("")"

Comment: you forgot the `(` `)`